# Set paging page size DropDownList in razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I would like to make in my asp.net web form page size selection with drop down list. Actually I made it already, but when I change page size from my drop down list there isn't change anything. I guess I need to write something extra in my controller, or maybe my View is wrong?

My Index.cshtml view:

```
@model TimeReportingWebApp.TimeReportViewMod
@using PagedList.Mvc;
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users"))
{
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string) 
        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.ActionLink("Login","Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LoginSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Model2) {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Login)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

Page @(Model.Model2.PageCount < Model.Model2.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.Model2.PageNumber) of @Model.Model2.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Model2, page => Url.Action("Index", 
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }) )

Select page size @Html.DropDownList("PageSize", new SelectList(new Dictionary<string, int> { { "10", 10 }, { "20", 20 }, { "100", 100 } }, "Key", "Value", Model.Model2.Count))
```

And this is my controller. Here I didn't added anything regarding DropDownList :

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString,  int? page)
{
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
    if (searchString != null)
    {
        page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        searchString = currentFilter;
    }
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
    var users = from s in db.Users.Include(u => u.CustomerProject).Include(u => u.Service).Include(u => u.Customer) select s;
    int pageSize = 20;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    var inst = new TimeReportViewMod();
    inst.Model1 = users.ToList();
    inst.Model2 = users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
    return View("Index", inst);
}
```

Comment: The view you have shown does not have a dropdownlist!

Comment: @StephenMuecke @Html.DropDownList("PageSize", new SelectList(new Dictionary<string, int> { { "10", 10 }, { "20", 20 }, { "100", 100 } }, "Key", "Value", Model.Model2.Count))

Comment: That's not in the form - it will not post back anything. It needs to be between the `<form>` tags. And then you need a parameter in your controller method for the value - `int pageSize`.

Comment: And change it to `@Html.DropDownList("PageSize", new SelectList(new List<int>{ 10, 20, 100 }))` or better, generate the `SelectList` in the controller

Comment: Yes as Stephen said, rename page to PageSize.

Comment: @BrianMains , how I am to change page to pageSize? It is stand for different things. page defines in which paging it is. And pageSize defines hardcoded size of page. I can't change or delete these things from my controller method parameter/.

Comment: @BinaryTie, You do not change `page` to `pageSize` - you add a new parameter `int pageSize` (and delete `int pageSize = 20;` inside the controller method)

Comment: Like Stephen said, selecting an item in a drop down doesn't do anything. It either needs to be inside your HTML `form` and then you must submit that form after selecting something, or you need to add a JS change handler to the select list and have that post the value automatically when an item is chosen.

Comment: @StephenMuecke it worked! When I putted Html.DropDownList in form. But!! I still need to pass some value in method, otherwise it shows errors. So I am passing this : Index(... ,... , int pageSize=20)

Comment: Yes the name of the dropdownlist in the form must match the field name.

Comment: @BinaryTie, No you don't. I'll add an answer explaining what you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the dropdownlist within you `<form>` tags so its value is submitted to the controller method, and that method also needs an additional parameter to bind to the value. You also need to include the selected value in the `Html.PagedListPager()` so that its retained when you go to another page.

You have not shown your `TimeReportViewMod` model, but its od that it contains properties `IEnumerable<User>` and `IPagedList<User>`, which is also `IEnumerable<User>` so the first one is unnecessary. But what it should contain is the properties you use for searching and filtering so that you can strongly bind to your properties and avoid the use of `ViewBag`. It should look like

```
public class TimeReportVM
{
    [Display(Name = "Find by name")]
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
    public string SortOrder { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Select page size")]
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public SelectList PageSizeList { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Note: Its not clear what `sortOrder` is for - you never use it anywhere. Nor do you ever use the value of `searchString`/`currentFilter` in you query.

Then you controller method is

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, int pageSize, int? page)
{
    if (searchString != null)
    {
        page = 1;
    }
    // this query should be taking into account the values of sortOrder and searchString?
    var users = from s in db.Users.Include(u => u.CustomerProject).Include(u => u.Service).Include(u => u.Customer) select s;
    TimeReportVM model = new TimeReportVM()
    {
        SortOrder = sortOrder,
        SearchString = searchString,
        PageSize = pageSize,
        PageSizeList = new SelectList(new int[]{ 10, 20, 100 }),
        Users = users.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, pageSize);
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view

```
@model TimeReportingWebApp.TimeReportViewMod
@using PagedList.Mvc;
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchString)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchString)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PageSize)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PageSize, Model.PageSizeList)
    <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
}
....
Page @(Model.Users.PageCount < Model.Users.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.Users.PageNumber) of @Model.Users.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Users, page => Url.Action("Index", 
    new { page, sortOrder = Model.SortOrder, searchString = Model.SearchString, pageSize = Model.PageSize }) )
```