# ASP.NET How to return Index module and with other Index return other module by having same partialview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, partial-views

I am trying to show list of items in my View. But unfortunately I am getting such a error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TimeReportingLib.User]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'TimeReportingWebApp.TimeReportViewMod'.

That is because in one index I am returning only `IEnumerable` list and in other index I am returning class with both modules `IEnumerable` and `IPagedList`.

Here is my class of both modules:

```
public class TimeReportViewMod
{
        public IEnumerable<TimeReportingLib.User> Model1 { get; set; }
        public IPagedList<TimeReportingLib.User> Model2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then this is my controller with both index methods:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var users = from s in db.Users.Include(u => u.CustomerProject)
                                  .Include(u => u.Service)
                                  .Include(u => u.Customer) 
                select s;
    return View(users.ToList());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString,
            string currentFilter, int? page, int pageSize = 20)
{
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
    ViewBag.LoginSortParm = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortOrder) ? "string" : "";

    if (searchString != null)
    {
        page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        searchString = currentFilter;
    }

    ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
    var users = from s in db.Users.Include(u => u.CustomerProject)
                                  .Include(u => u.Service)
                                  .Include(u => u.Customer) 
                select s;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        users = users.Where(s => s.Login.Contains(searchString) || s.UserName.Contains(searchString));
    }

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "string":
             users = users.OrderByDescending(s => s.Login);
             break;

        default:
             users = users.OrderBy(s => s.Login);
             break;
    }

    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

    var inst = new TimeReportViewMod();
    inst.Model1 = users.ToList();
    inst.Model2 = users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

    return View("_UserGrid", inst);
}
```

This is my partial view:

```
@model TimeReportViewMod
<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Model2)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Login)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

And here is my very complicated Index View:

```
@model TimeReportingWebApp.TimeReportViewMod
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Users";
}    
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
</head>    
<h2>Users</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", FormMethod.Get)
</p>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "UserDiv" }))
{
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string) 
        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
    </p>
    <form class="control-label col-md-2">
        <p>
            List by: @Html.DropDownList("PageSize", new SelectList(new List<int> { 10, 20, 50, 100 }), new { @class = "form-control" })
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
            @*page size @Html.DropDownList("PageSize", new SelectList(new List<> {10 , 20 , 100 } , "Key", "Value", Model.Model2.Count))*@
        </p>
    </form>

    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Login", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LoginSortParm }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "UserDiv", InsertionMode= InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod="POST" })
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</table>
}
<div id="UserDiv">
    @Html.Partial("_UserGrid", Model.Model2)
</div>
```

So as you see in Index view and in partial view I am using same module. But in my controller in Index method i am returning just simple list. Which is not very good. It requires both modules. But I would like to leave by returning just a list of items in my first Index.

Comment: You need to go back an carefully read the answer to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548832/set-paging-page-size-dropdownlist-in-razor-view)

Comment: You also have nested forms which is invalid html and not supported.

Comment: @StephenMuecke My previous question is very clear after your answer, but I am very confused at this time, because I would like to return with one Index my Index view with final result and with other Index return partial-view with all Index logic which is defined in Index controller.

Comment: @StephenMuecke in which part is nested forms?

Comment: You have ignored almost all of the code in the previous answer :) And inside `@using (Ajax.BeginForm()) you have another `<form class="control-label col-md-2">`

Comment: @StephenMuecke That explain me a lot, because I was working on that yesterday and I was wondering why it apears another form in form when I click on ajax action link :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109119/discussion-between-binarytie-and-stephen-muecke).